# Removing someone from a family plan

Tags: icloud, family-sharing

I have a 200 GB family plan shared with one other person.

If I remove that other person from the plan, what happens to that other person's photos, videos, and other files stored in iCloud?

Are they just deleted?  Is there some grace period to make alternate arrangements?  Will someone's iphone catch on fire?  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Their data should not be immediately deleted, instead their syncing might be disabled until the situation is remedied.

**However,** if that person has more than 5GB of iCloud data used (refer to Settings > Apple ID & iCloud > iCloud > Manage Account Storage > Family Usage) then **they should upgrade their storage first.**

The other user should be able to subscribe and receive iCloud Storage allotment directly, even if you are sharing it.